# graphviz three ranks layout with subgraphs

Tags: graphviz, rank, dot

I'm trying to position elements in a form of an automatically generated flow-diagram.
In general, `inputs` (green) should be on the very left, `outputs` (red) on the very right and the rest should be placed in the center according to the layout.
I'm using `rank=source` and `rank=sink` for this.
Within a standard graph it works nicely.

However, when I start nesting graphs, the `rank=source` seems not to work. I expect the three inputs of the <> (electricity, switch, room_temperature) to be placed on the very left (as it's happening within the subgraphs) and the subgraphs + states (brown circles) and blue boxes between inputs and outputs.

Is there a way to specify "rank=center" (or something similar?)

I have gone through the [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) but did not find the correct attributes (and where to specify them).

[image: MWE]

```
digraph MyGraph {
    node [fontsize=8  margin=".1,.01" width=.5 height=.5 shape=box]
    edge [fontsize=8]
    rankdir=LR;
    ranksep = .25;
    nodesep= .5;

subgraph cluster_4386357488 {
    label = " <<GrowLamp>>"
    style=solid
    {rank=source;
        4386357544 [label="electricity" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
        4386357712 [label="room_temperature" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
        4386357768 [label="switch" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
    }
    {
        4386357880 [label="off" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
        4386357936 [label="on" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=circle]
        4386357656 [label="on_time" style=filled fillcolor="#d2ceef"]
    }
    {rank=sink;
        4386357600 [label="light" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
        4386357824 [label="temperature" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
    }
    4386357880 -> 4386357936
    4386357936 -> 4386357880
    {
        subgraph cluster_4386357992 {
            label = "<<Adder>>"
            style=dashed
            {rank=source;
                4386358048 [label="heat_in" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
                4386358104 [label="room_temp_in" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
            }
            {
                4386358216 [label="state" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
            }
            {rank=sink;
                4386358160 [label="temperature" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
            }
            4386358216 -> 4386358160 [style="dashed"]
        }


        subgraph cluster_4386358328 {
            label = "<<HeatElement>>"
            style=solid
            {rank=source;
                4386358384 [label="electricity" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
            }
            {
                4386358496 [label="on" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
            }
            {rank=sink;
                4386358440 [label="heat" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
            }
            4386358496 -> 4386358440 [style="dashed"]
        }


        subgraph cluster_4386358608 {
            label = "<<LightElement>>"
            style=solid
            {rank=source;
                4386358664 [label="electricity" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
            }
            {
                4386358776 [label="off" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
                4386358832 [label="on" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=circle]
            }
            {rank=sink;
                4386358720 [label="light" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
            }
            4386358776 -> 4386358832
            4386358832 -> 4386358776
            4386358776 -> 4386358720 [style="dashed"]
            4386358832 -> 4386358720 [style="dashed"]
        }

        4386358160 -> 4386357824
        4386357712 -> 4386358104
        4386358440 -> 4386358048
        4386358720 -> 4386357600
        4386357936 -> 4386358384 [style="dashed"]
        4386357936 -> 4386358664 [style="dashed"]
        4386357936 -> 4386357656 [style="dashed"]
    }

}
```

---

**Hopeful solution:**
Here is what I would like to end up with. Note how the green boxes are all on the left within their respective subgraphs, and the red boxes are on the right. Between there should be the rest of the elements, positioned by graphviz.

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: There isn't a rank=center, but there are other ways to get the nodes to align the way you would like. I have an idea about how to help you, but I'm very unclear about the desired arrangement. Do you want all of the green boxes on the left, the brown circles in the middle, and the orange boxes on the right? Or do you just wan some of them that way? Could you add a rough sketch of how you want the elements arranged?

Comment: I added an image explaining what I want. In every box, the green boxes (inputs) should be on the left, the red boxes (outputs) on the right, the rest in the centre (as `dot` sees fit). Hence there should be a kind of "flow" from left to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the layout you want by adding invisible edges to connect the three inputs to the rest of the diagram so that the graphviz layout algorithm can calculate their rank correctly. You can make any edge invisible by adding `style=invis` to the edge formatting.

```
digraph MyGraph {
    node [fontsize=8  margin=".1,.01" width=.5 height=.5 shape=box]
    edge [fontsize=8]
    rankdir=LR;
    ranksep = .25;
    nodesep= .5;

subgraph cluster_4386357488 {
    label = " <<GrowLamp>>"
    style=solid
    {rank=source;
        4386357544 [label="electricity" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
        4386357712 [label="room_temperature" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
        4386357768 [label="switch" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
    }
    {
        4386357880 [label="off" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
        4386357936 [label="on" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=circle]
        4386357656 [label="on_time" style=filled fillcolor="#d2ceef"]
    }
    {rank=sink;
        4386357600 [label="light" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
        4386357824 [label="temperature" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
    }
    4386357880 -> 4386357936
    4386357936 -> 4386357880
    #invisible edges added to achieve correct layout
    4386357544 -> 4386357880 [style="invis"]
    4386357712 -> 4386357880 [style="invis"]
    4386357768 -> 4386357880 [style="invis"]

    {
        subgraph cluster_4386357992 {
            label = "<<Adder>>"
            style=dashed
            {rank=source;
                4386358048 [label="heat_in" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
                4386358104 [label="room_temp_in" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
            }
            {
                4386358216 [label="state" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
            }
            {rank=sink;
                4386358160 [label="temperature" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
            }
            4386358216 -> 4386358160 [style="dashed"]
        }


        subgraph cluster_4386358328 {
            label = "<<HeatElement>>"
            style=solid
            {rank=source;
                4386358384 [label="electricity" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
            }
            {
                4386358496 [label="on" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
            }
            {rank=sink;
                4386358440 [label="heat" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
            }
            4386358496 -> 4386358440 [style="dashed"]
        }


        subgraph cluster_4386358608 {
            label = "<<LightElement>>"
            style=solid
            {rank=source;
                4386358664 [label="electricity" style=filled fillcolor="#b5fed9"]
            }
            {
                4386358776 [label="off" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=doublecircle]
                4386358832 [label="on" style=filled fillcolor="#e2cbc1" shape=circle]
            }
            {rank=sink;
                4386358720 [label="light" style=filled fillcolor="#fcc5b3"]
            }
            4386358776 -> 4386358832
            4386358832 -> 4386358776
            4386358776 -> 4386358720 [style="dashed"]
            4386358832 -> 4386358720 [style="dashed"]
        }

        4386358160 -> 4386357824
        4386357712 -> 4386358104
        4386358440 -> 4386358048
        4386358720 -> 4386357600
        4386357936 -> 4386358384 [style="dashed"]
        4386357936 -> 4386358664 [style="dashed"]
        4386357936 -> 4386357656 [style="dashed"]
    }

}
}
```

With `dot.exe` version 2.38 you should get a graph like:

[image: Nodes aligned correctly to graph source and sink.]

Comment: I've been trying to understand why the solution works with invisible edges but not without them. My suspicion is that dot can only align the nodes if they are connected to the rest of the graph, but I'm not sure about it.
Can you tell me if that's correct? @Craig

Comment: @S.K.- My understanding of this comes from some testing I did when answering your question. The edge between "room_temperature" and "room_temp_in" is causing `dot` to place "room_temperature" one rank lower than "room_temp_in". This seems to override the positioning of this node at the lowest rank and may be a bug. It also forces the "electricity" and "switch" nodes to get placed on the same rank and not the lowest rank. If you delete this edge from your original file, you will get the desired layout, albeit missing the one edge.